# receiving "framework not found MeasurementNanoPB" error on updating firebase pods to latest version

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-analytics

Earlier was using **5.7.0** but there are some issue related to firebase storage. to find the solution of this I read somewhere that I need to update the firebase with latest version **i.e 5.12.0 Or greater**.

I am updating a new version but facing **"framework not found MeasurementNanoPB" error**. Search a lot regarding the same but no solution found.

There are no relavent steps, anyone who have updated firabse with latest version might have received the same error.

- Tried manually installing the firebase sdk.

Comment: Even I tried with Carthage, still having the same issue. In both cases I have included **nanopb.framework** in the **Linked Framework and Libraries** but still no luck.

Comment: Even tried searching google for MeasurementNanoPB.framework to install locally but no luck :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Resolved!**

Tried deleting Pod.lock file, removed all the pods related to firebase from the Podfile. install pod without firebase. When it is done, add all the pods one by one for firebase.

It still gives an error for **"GRPCClient not found**". Add below framework in Podfile.
pod gRPC-ProtoRPC.

Then got error for **"measurement nanopb.framework"** not found so just follow below steps:
1) Clean project
2) Remove derived data from respective folder
3) Now search for "nanopb" in whole project(you will find under OtherLinkerFlags) and remove it.
4) Now Install POD again.

And you are done. Now the project will run without errors.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/ios
Version 5.14.0 - December 4, 2018, fixes this:
The FirebaseAnalytics CocoaPod corrects its dependency on the GoogleAppMeasurement CocoaPod (#2151).

Did you try to update to Firebase 5.14.0 ?

Otherwise, did you try to include `pod 'Firebase/Performance'`in your podfile ?

Comment: `Firebase/Performance` include `FirebaseABTesting.framework` , `FirebasePerformance.framework` , `FirebaseRemoteConfig.framework` , `GoogleToolboxForMac.framework` , `GTMSessionFetcher.framework` & `Protobuf.framework`. There is nothing `MeasurementNanoPB.framework` there. It suppose not to work.